Where can I find a native English speaker to proofread my text?
Where can I find a reliable native English speaker to proofread my text, which is a translation, ensuring that it is free of grammatical errors and sounds natural to native speakers? Please avoid suggesting online services similar to Fiverr, as there is no guarantee that the person offering proofreading services is actually a native speaker.
Maybe someone on this forum would like to serve as a proofreader?

How do I find an affordable editor? lists a website with accredited editors. Does that work? More details would be helpful, if not. Asking about proofreading just "text" is awfully broad, since editing can be very specialized to the subject matter.

Thank you. I looked at those suggestions. They don't look reliable.

I just googled "proofreading native English speaker" and found several companies that appear to offer that service. Might be easier to check the credentials of a company than an individual on fiverr.

Of course I googled it, it's not as easy as it sounds. But thank you for your contribution.

Put an ad in your local newspaper for a native English speaker to proofread your text. Ask to meet the candidate in person to judge if he or she has an English accent or talk to the person on the phone. Meeting in person is best since you cannot be sure by phone.

I'm in Ukraine. In my local newspaper, no native speaker will read my ad.

If you have specific questions, https://ell.stackexchange.com/ is an excellent resource.

That's an interesting solution, I hadn't thought of that. Perhaps I can find the right person on the forum you suggested.

Proofreading is explicitly off-topic on both ELL and ELU.  Asking there could get you a question ban very quickly.

@AndreyI. Please note what Chenmunka has mentioned. If you want to use ELL as a resource, don't ask for general proofreading. Rather, formulate and ask questions about specific topics that you're not sure of.

How long is your text and what is it about? I don't know of any services that you could find someone with so I'd suggest continuing to search online, but depending on what the text is, I might be willing to proofread for you. I'm a native English speaker and a writer myself, so I could be of some help (if you'd like).

It's a book. You can check it out here: https://www.amazon.com/Math-Bitcoin-Price-Prediction-2030-ebook/dp/B0DHV5TVYG
If you find the topic interesting, connect with me on LinkedIn: https://www.linkedin.com/in/andrey-ignatenko-btc/ Tell me you're from this forum, I'll understand. Then we'll discuss it.
But I am preparing a second edition, so proofreading will be needed for slightly different text.

This is clearly spam.
